# Does Wikimedia supports other formats for storing data rather than wiki text?

Tags: xml, wikimedia, wikitext

I have some XML files that I need to store in Wikimedia.

The obvious alternative will be to parse the content, format it with WikiText markup and store it.

I would like to know if Wikimedia supports natively (or through plugins) other formats to store data?

And / or if this can be easily implemented?

Answer (score 1):

You can upload them as files, or as a [custom content type](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:ContentHandler) ([example](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:TEI) of such an extension), or store it as structured data with something like [Semantic MediaWiki](https://www.semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Semantic_MediaWiki) or [Cargo](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Cargo).